# Low Search Form + CE Cache's Static Driver; What's Needed to Make it Work?

Tags: low-search, ce-cache

I'm using CE Cache's Static driver, which essentially uses EE to generate the first view of a page, and then saves the output to a text file, which is served on subsequent page views; pretty easy to setup, and, super fast.

We have a simple, keywords only, Low Search form in the header of every page on our site. It looks like it includes a couple of fields that might be unique to the user/session/cookie, `XID`, and, possibly, `param`?

When another user comes in and performs a search on a cached page, they're getting an error - "you are not authorized to perform this action."

Is there anything I can do to get the Low Search form working? Any potential "gotchas" to just building a form that will GET to generate the correct URL, e.g. example.com/search/?keywords=widget ?

Currently using EE 2.7.2, Low Search 3.0.3 (I just saw that that's out of date now), and CE Cache 1.10.1.

Comment: Before anything, I'd upgrade to the latest version of Low Search, and see if the problem persists. There was some work done with the whole XID bit.

Comment: Will update and report back as soon as I can on this, which will likely be next week. Was able to work around with no apparent ill-effect by just building a form that builds the correct URL.

Comment: @Low, thanks for patching that bug, it looks like it's cleared up the issue relating to XID (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (were) two issues at play here:

**Bug with Relying on XID Would Break Search Form for Users who Didn't Generate Cached Version of Page**

The search form's `XID` getting cached on non-results pages *was* causing trouble, but appears to be resolved upgrading from Low Search 3.0.3 to 3.1.2. I'll attempt to check back in and confirm this, but early testing looks promising.

**Low Search Results with CE Cache Static Driver**

When search results pages are built with a query string (`example.com/search/?keywords=foo`, CE Cache's static driver ignores (rightfully so) query strings.

This can be worked around by using [encoded queries](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/settings#encode-query) which replace the human readable query string `/?keywords=foo` with hashed segment `eyJrZXl3b3JkcyI6ImhlbGxvIHdvcmxkIn0`, which should play nicely with CE Cache's static driver.

In the event that encoded queries are unacceptable, any of CE Cache's non-static methods should work just fine.